# Unable to start debugging Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

This is really weird, I cannot start debugging on one project but have no problem with another one. The one I'm stuck with gives me the following error message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  Unable to connect to the
>   web server.  Verify that the web server is running and that incoming
>   HTTP requests are not blocked by a firewall.

I tried the following which didn't work:

1. Reset IIS
2. Re-register ASP.NET by running `aspnet_regiis -i`
3. Reboot and clear out all temp files for that project
4. Checked IIS virtual folder is correct
5. Confirmed security is set to Windows Integrated
6. Confirmed web.config has `debugging= true`

What other steps could I take?

Comment: Did you check the `framework version of the app pool`? **In project properties;** Have you `set the debuger to asp.net`, checked `Use custom web server` and given a `correct web server uri which matches iis binding`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is running in IIS 5.1, no application pool in my case. And the funny thing is it was working fine before

Answer (score 1):

reboot resolved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, instead of keeping the question open for years.